# Android App Slows Down/Becomes Unresponsive When TextView is Added

Tags: android, android-studio

I've been developing this Android game, and I was wondering why whenever I add this TextView, my app starts becoming unresponsive. Like, some of my buttons won't press, while others do, and so on and so forth. Then, when I remove the TextView from the linear layout, everything goes back to normal. Please help!

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

boolean started = false;
boolean place;
boolean[] tiles = new boolean[60];
int prevId = 0;
int times = 0;
ArrayList<Integer> IDs = new ArrayList<>();

Typeface face;
TextView num;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    num = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.count);

    face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/ZonaPro-Bold.otf");

    num.setTypeface(face);
}

public void press(View view)
{
    place = false;
    int id = view.getId() % 2131427400;
    String test = "" + id;

    ImageView img = (ImageView) view;

    Log.d("TEST", test);

    *****HERE, I HAVE LOTS OF LOGIC, AND IF-STATEMENTS INCLUDING SOME UNIMPORTANT VARIABLES*****

    int abs = Math.abs(Math.abs(id - prevId));

    if(place && (abs == 1 || abs == 8) && tiles[id] == false && !(img.getTag().toString().equals("bound")))
    {
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue_sphere);
        tiles[id] = true;
        prevId = id;
        times++;
        IDs.add(id);
        num.setText("" + times);
    }
}

public void start(View view)
{
    ImageView v = (ImageView) view;

    if(!started)
    {
        started = true;
        v.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue_sphere);
        tiles[22] = true;
        prevId = 22;
        IDs.add(22);
        num = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.count);
        num.setText("0");
    }
}

public void undo(View view)
{

    for(int ID : IDs)
    {
        ImageView re = (ImageView) findViewById(2131427400 + ID);
        Log.d("TAG", re.getTag().toString());

        if(re.getTag().toString().equals("tile"))
            re.setImageResource(R.drawable.gray_block);
        else if(re.getTag().toString().equals("start"))
        {
            re.setImageResource(R.drawable.start_tile);
            started = false;
        }
        else if(re.getTag().toString().equals("bound"))
        {
            re.setImageResource(R.drawable.newer_x);
        }
        else if(re.getTag().toString().equals("goal"))
        {
            re.setImageResource(R.drawable.new_goal);
        }
    }

    Arrays.fill(tiles, false);
    times = 0;
}
}
```

Activity_Main.xml (all of the these layouts are within a larger, horizontal linear layout)

```
<!-- 1 -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="9">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/_11"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/gray_block"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="press"
        android:tag="tile" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/_12"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/gray_block"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="press"
        android:tag="tile"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/_13"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/gray_block"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="press"
        android:tag="tile"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/_14"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/newer_x"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="press"
        android:tag="bound"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/_15"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/gray_block"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="press"
        android:tag="tile"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/_16"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/gray_block"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="press"
        android:tag="tile"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/_17"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/gray_block"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="press"
        android:tag="tile"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/_18"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/start_tile"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="start"
        android:tag="start" />

****this is the text view I'm having problems with****

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/count"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

******************************************************

</LinearLayout>

<!-- 2 -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="9">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/_21"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/gray_block"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="press"
        android:tag="tile" />


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/_22"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/gray_block"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="press"
        android:tag="tile"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/_23"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/gray_block"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="press"
        android:tag="tile"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/_24"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/gray_block"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="press"
        android:tag="tile"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/_25"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/gray_block"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="press"
        android:tag="tile"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/_26"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/gray_block"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="press"
        android:tag="tile"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/_27"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/gray_block"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="press"
        android:tag="tile"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/_28"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/gray_block"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="press"
        android:tag="tile"/>

</LinearLayout>

<!-- 3 -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="9">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/_31"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/newer_x"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="press"
        android:tag="bound" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/_32"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/newer_x"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="press"
        android:tag="bound" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/_33"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/newer_x"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="press"
        android:tag="bound" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/_34"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/gray_block"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="press"
        android:tag="tile"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/_35"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/gray_block"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="press"
        android:tag="tile"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/_36"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/gray_block"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="press"
        android:tag="tile"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/_37"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/newer_x"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="press"
        android:tag="bound"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/_38"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/gray_block"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="press"
        android:tag="tile"/>

</LinearLayout>

<!-- 4 -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="9">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/_41"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/gray_block"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="press"
        android:tag="tile" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/_42"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/gray_block"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="press"
        android:tag="tile"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/_43"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/gray_block"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="press"
        android:tag="tile"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/_44"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/gray_block"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="press"
        android:tag="tile"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/_45"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/gray_block"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="press"
        android:tag="tile"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/_46"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/newer_x"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="press"
        android:tag="bound"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/_47"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/gray_block"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="press"
        android:tag="tile"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/_48"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/gray_block"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="press"
        android:tag="tile"/>

</LinearLayout>

<!-- 5 -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="9">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/_51"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/new_goal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="press"
        android:tag="goal" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/_52"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/gray_block"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="press"
        android:tag="tile"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/_53"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/gray_block"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="press"
        android:tag="tile"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/_54"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/gray_block"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="press"
        android:tag="tile"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/_55"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/gray_block"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="press"
        android:tag="tile"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/_56"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/gray_block"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="press"
        android:tag="tile"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/_57"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/gray_block"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="press"
        android:tag="tile"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/_58"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/gray_block"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="press"
        android:tag="tile"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/undo"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/newer_undo"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="undo"
        android:tag="undo"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I'm sorry for posting so much code, but I have no idea why this is happening, and I'm hoping the issue is somewhere in these files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your `start(View view)` onClick method, You are referencing the TextView which is already instantiated in `onCreate(Bundle obj)` please try removing it. And replace fill_parent to match_parent.

Answer (score 0):

May be problem with below line

```
//TextView num;
```

First uncomment this.

Then Don't declare below line again(Already declare in onCreate)

```
 num = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.count);
```

Remove it from onStart().

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem is still occurring. Literally, the fact that this TextView exists where it is now is the issue, but I don't know what to do about it.